# Sql Query for getting a required result

Tags: sql-server

my table is like this

```
SlNo    Date                 Session    MemberCode  Litres  Fat     Price   Amount  GS     Col1   Col
16   2013-07-02 16:27:17.000    E           0        1.00   0.00    28.00   28.00   NULL    S     NULL
17   2013-07-08 16:55:26.000    E           1        38.00  3.80    17.56   667.28  4.00    P     NULL
18   2013-07-08 22:10:03.000    E           0        0.00   3.90    17.63   0.00    0.00    GT     -         
19   2013-07-08 23:03:08.000    E           2        2.00   3.50    17.50   35.00   4.00    P      -         
20   2013-07-08 23:03:22.000    E           13       3.90   3.80    17.56   68.48   4.00    P      -
```

I want a query to get the result as

```
Date, 
Session, 
Total Members for session, 
Total Litres for Session, 
Total Amount For the Session,  
Fat(Where Col1='GT') as GTFat, 
Price(Where Col1='GT') as GTPrice, 
NetAmount as GTPrice * (TotalLitres for Session), 
Profit or Loss(NetAmount-Session Amount)
```

Please help me how can I get the resullt.

Thanks in Advance

I tried with this code but unable to get the required result as there is a problem with date comparison

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (SlNo INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL, Date DATETIME, Session VARCHAR(30), TotalMembers INT, TotalLitres DECIMAL(8, 2), Amount DECIMAL(8, 2), 
GTFat DECIMAL(8, 2), GTPrice DECIMAL(8, 2), GTAmount DECIMAL(8, 2), PnL DECIMAL(8, 2)); 
INSERT INTO @t (Date, Session, TotalMembers, TotalLitres, Amount)        
SELECT  Cast(Date as date), Session, Count(MemberCode), Sum(Litres), Sum(Amount)  FROM   myTable Where Col1 = 'P' and Date between '2013-07-01'  and '2013-07-09' GROUP BY Cast(Date as Date), Session Order By Cast(Date as date)

declare @maxcount int,@loop int
    declare @GTAmt money,@PL money
    set @loop =1
    select @maxcount= MAX(SlNo ) from @t
while(@loop <= @maxcount)
    begin
Update @t Set GTFat = (Select Fat From myTable Where Date=Date and Session=Session and Col1='GT'),GTPrice=(Select Price From myTable Where Date=Date and Session=Session and Col1='GT')
set @loop = @loop + 1
end 
SELECT * FROM @t order by Cast(Date as date)
```

Comment: Can you show us your tries?

Comment: @user2464277 Where is **`Session Amount`** ?

Comment: Session amount is Total Amount for the session

Comment: What you are looking for is Sum() and GroupBy(). `SELECT Sum(Litres), Sum(Amount), ... , Session From yourtable Group By Session `. I can't produce a whole statement, since I don't know what Col1 is. In addition you'd want to group by Date first and then by Session.

Comment: This is something like this >>> Select Date,Session,Count(MemberCode),Sum(Litres),Sum(Amount),Fat as GTFat, Price as GTPrice ( this is for the Date and session which u have selected before where it will be a single row for that particular date/session and you will get multiple rows for Litres and Fat and ....), Sum(Litres)*GTPrice as GTAmount, GTAmount-Sum(Amount) as PnL from myTable where Date ='2013-07-08' Group by Date, Session

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need something like this, but what do you really mean by net amount? you want to calculate it? 
 Date, 
Session, 
Total Members for session, 
Total Litres for Session, 
Total Amount For the Session,
Fat(Where Col1='GT') as GTFat, 
Price(Where Col1='GT') as GTPrice, 
NetAmount as GTPrice * (TotalLitres for Session), 
Profit or Loss(NetAmount-Session Amount)

SELECT

```
 Date, 
Session, 
COUNT(Session) AS TotalnumberForSession,
SUM(amount) AS TotalSumAmount,
CASE 
    WHEN Col1 = 'GT' THEN Fat
    ELSE NULL
END AS GTPrice,
CASE 
    WHEN Col1 = 'GT' THEN Price
    ELSE NULL
END AS GTFAT,
amount*SUM(litres) OVER (PARTITION BY session)
```

Comment: I tried with this code but unable to get the required result as there is a problem with date comparison

Comment: you need to manipulate that code somehow, what kind of problem you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.

I obtained the result by writing a **stored procedure.**

Created a temporary table and collected all required data in to that and got the result.

Instead of stored procedure I could have used temporary table directly... that is the second option as far as my knowledge.

Thanks once again